# How to move a ListViewItem part of a Group in place of another ListViewItem using the same ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Below I'm trying to move `item4` in place of `item5`, the action I expected was for item 4 to be on top of `item5` and item5 under `item4`:

[image: ListViewItem Move to Group]

Below I'm trying to move item4 in place of `item5`, the action I expected was for `item4` to be on top of `item5` and `item5` under `item4`:

[image: ListViewItem Move to wrong position]

I also can't move one item in place of another, can anyone help?

I leave the complete code here, including the design:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ListView listView;
        private ListViewItem currentVieItem;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            createListview();
        }

        public void createListview()
        {
            listView = new ListView();
            listView.AllowDrop = true;

            listView.ItemDrag += new ItemDragEventHandler(OnItemDrag);
            listView.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(OnDragOver);
            listView.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(OnDragDrop);

            // MY CODE HERE
            ColumnHeader columnHeader = new ColumnHeader();
            listView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            columnHeader});
            listView.HideSelection = false;
            int indexGroup = 1;
            ListViewGroup group = new ListViewGroup();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    string nmGroup = $"Group {indexGroup}";
                    group = new ListViewGroup() { Header = nmGroup};
                    listView.Groups.Add(group);
                    indexGroup++;
                }
                listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = $"Item {i}", Group = group });
            }
            listView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            listView.Name = "listView1";
            listView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(436, 494);
            listView.TabIndex = 0;
            listView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            listView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            // 
            // columnHeader1
            // 
            columnHeader.Text = "Items";
            columnHeader.Width = 382;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(937, 600);
            this.Controls.Add(listView);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public void OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var pos = listView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            var hit = listView.HitTest(pos);
            this.currentVieItem = hit.Item;
            this.Text = hit.Item?.Index.ToString();

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)))
            {
                e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
            }
        }

        public void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentVieItem == null) return;

            int index = currentVieItem.Index;
            this.Text = index.ToString();

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)))
            {
                if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem current in (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)))
                    {
                        current.Remove();
                        current.Group = currentVieItem.Group;
                        listView.Items.Insert(index, current);
                        index++;
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }

        public void OnItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.DoDragDrop(listView.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the [ListViewItem.Group.Items.Insert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.insert) method works as intended (the Item is inserted at the specified position), the Group itself doesn't sort its items based on the Index (the Group Index) assigned to the new Item.
The existing order of Items takes precedence, so the new Item is added last.

You can redefine this behavior if you assign to the ListView a custom [ListViewItemSorter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter), based on your own criteria, when you change the order of the Items.

You can remove the `currentViewItem` reference, it's not more necessary. See the code.
The `DragOver` event handler is also not required, but it could be used to show an [InsertionMark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark), eventually.

Keep the initialization of the ListView, changing the names of the handlers:

```
// [...]
listView.ItemDrag += OnLVItemDrag;
listView.DragEnter += OnLVDragEnter;
listView.DragDrop += OnLVDragDrop;
// [...]
```

Replace the code in the event handlers:

```
public void OnLVItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    var lv = sender as ListView;
    lv.DoDragDrop(lv.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void OnLVDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) => e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;

public void OnLVDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)) as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection;
    if (data is null) return;

    var lv = sender as ListView;
    var nearestItem = lv.HitTest(lv.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Item;
    if (nearestItem is null) return;

    var groupIndex = nearestItem.Group.Items.IndexOf(nearestItem);

    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move) {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in data) {
            // Item dropped over itself or Items dropped over the same selection
            if (nearestItem == item) continue;
            nearestItem.Group.Items.Remove(item);
            nearestItem.Group.Items.Insert(groupIndex, item);
            if (nearestItem.Group != item.Group) groupIndex++;
        }
        listView.Sort();
    }
    // else{} Handle other operations
}
```

**Custom `ListViewItemSorter` object**:

This custom object can sort a ListView based on the SubItem's `Text` Property (default), or the Items' Index or the Group Index.

```
using System.Collections;

class ListViewSorter : IComparer {
    int columnIdx = 0;
    bool indexSort = false;
    bool sortGroups = false;

    public ListViewSorter() { }
    public ListViewSorter(int column) => columnIdx = column;

    public ListViewSorter(bool sortByIndex, bool useGroupIndex) { 
        sortGroups = useGroupIndex;
        indexSort = sortByIndex;
    }

    public int Compare(object lvi1, object lvi2)
    {
        var item1 = lvi1 as ListViewItem;
        var item2 = lvi2 as ListViewItem;
        if (indexSort) {
            if (sortGroups && item1.Group != null && item2.Group != null) {
                int idx1 = item1.Group.Items.IndexOf(item1);
                int idx2 = item2.Group.Items.IndexOf(item2);
                return idx1 - idx2;
            }
            else {
                return item1.Index - item2.Index;
            }
        }
        else {
            return string.Compare(
                item1.SubItems[columnIdx].Text, 
                item2.SubItems[columnIdx].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: ListViewItem Groups DragDrop]

Comment: seems not working for .net6 , it's weird that the line "nearestItem.Group.Items.Insert(groupIndex, item)" makes items added to the collection only but not updated to the view. I see item untouched after every dragdrop as nearestItem.Group.Items.Count increases. Otherwise, var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)) as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection is always null too. Weird!

Comment: @Xiaoyuvax Code tested in .Net 6 and works as expected (except the bug now fixed). If the DataObject contains null data, the Drag operation was not started correctly (i.e., something was left behind on your side). -- If `nullable` is active, you need to change all `object` in `object?` and add the null-forgiving token to some of the references (e.g., `private ListView? listView; // [...] listView = new ListView(); // [...] listView!.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewSorter(sortByIndex: true, useGroupIndex: true);`) -- Not related to the behavior though.

Comment: @dr.null There was another bug: if you drag a selection over itself, one of the items just removed has null Group (because it's itself). Fixed that too (now it just re-index) and added a note -- Of course if you drop the items outside the bounds of any Item in any Group, in `var nearestItem = lv.HitTest(lv.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Item;` then `nearestItem` is null (because that's how `HitTest()` works). But the DataObject is not null nor is `data`; You could remap `new Point(e.X, e.Y)` so that `e.X` is always near the left edge of the Control. Not sure this is a good thing.