# C# Drag and Drop in Listview doesn't work with Groups

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a Listview with Drag and Drop codes working well.
However, after i add groups to it, the Drag and Drop codes are run, but the outcome is not what the codes used to behave.
Dropped items were only added to the tail of its group.
Why? and how to get it work properly with groups?

The Drag and Drop procedures are given herebelow:

```
private void lvQ_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int targetIndex = lvQ.InsertionMark.Index;
    if (targetIndex == -1)
        return;
    if (lvQ.InsertionMark.AppearsAfterItem)
        targetIndex++;

    ListViewItem draggedItem = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));

    if (targetIndex == 0 && lvQ.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault()?.SubItems[1].Text == "FF")
    {
        lvQ.InsertionMark.Index = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        lvQ.BeginUpdate();
        lvQ.Items.Insert(targetIndex, (ListViewItem)draggedItem.Clone());
        lvQ.Items.Remove(draggedItem);
        lvQ.EndUpdate();
        ShowTXFrameStr();
    }
}

private void lvQ_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
}

private void lvQ_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvQ.InsertionMark.Index = -1;
}

private void lvQ_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point ptScreen = new(e.X, e.Y);
    Point pt = lvQ.PointToClient(ptScreen);

    int targetIndex = lvQ.InsertionMark.NearestIndex(pt);
    if (targetIndex > -1)
    {
        Rectangle itemBounds = lvQ.GetItemRect(targetIndex);
        lvQ.InsertionMark.AppearsAfterItem = pt.Y > itemBounds.Top + (itemBounds.Height / 2);
    }
    lvQ.InsertionMark.Index = targetIndex;
}

private void lvQ_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    lvQ.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72119825/14171304

Comment: thanks for ur link, but the code provided by that solution doesn't work here, i guess might be something different in winform .net 6? I left comments in that link.

Comment: Make sure you drop over the bounds of a LVI. The label area, You will get `null` as you commented there if you drop elsewhere over the control. The answer has been revised. Check it out.